# Two-dimensional table with row/column highlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need a table with `N` rows and `M` columns.

The touch event in the table should cause highlighting of current column and row, and when released triggered an action.

By means of what is possible to write such a table?

I thought of using `2D` array of `UIView`/`UIButtons` to make the table, and putting invisible `UIView` over this table to handle touch action.

What do you think? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

**Option 1.** Two dimensional array of **UIButtons**.

```
- (void)setupButtons
{
    int N = 3;
    int M = 3;
    CGFloat buttonSize = 50.0f;
    CGFloat padding = 5.0f;

    CGPoint startButtonLocation = CGPointMake(40.0f, 40.0f);
    CGPoint buttonLocation;

    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        buttonLocation.x = startButtonLocation.x + n * (buttonSize + padding);

        for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
        {
            buttonLocation.y = startButtonLocation.y + m * (buttonSize + padding);

            UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonLocation.x,
                                                                          buttonLocation.y,
                                                                          buttonSize,
                                                                          buttonSize)];
            button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i, %i", n, m]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(buttonTapped:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [self.view addSubview:button];
        }
    }
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tapped index: %@", ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text);
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Option 2.** Implementing **[UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)**.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
}

@implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];

    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}
```

Output:

[image]

When user taps an item, you can handle it in:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Handling
}
```

Comment: The most important thing for which I want to use custom table - tracking of touch point and highlighting the corresponding row and column. Using UICollectionView is no possibility to do this, right?

Comment: It is possible. You can achieve this with `UICollectionView`. When user selects an item in a `UICollectionView`, the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`
 method will be called.

Comment: I don't have 15 rep. for upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a matrix, as you suggest, or an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`.

But with the description you give of what you attempt to achieve, it sound very much like something `UICollectionView` can solve for you. From a coding point it behaves almost like a `UITableView`,  but allows you to create a grid of cells:

*Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts. Collection views support customizable layouts that can be used to implement multi-column grids, tiled layouts, circular layouts, and many more.*

Take a look at the full [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html).